# Scroll function gets ignored

Tags: jquery, css

I have a website which I want to add `overflow: auto` to it. Now when I do that my jQuery code (scroll) gets ignored.

```
html, body{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

```js
function smallTopCheck() {
    if ($window.width() < 992) {
        $document.on('scroll', function() {
           console.log("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I need the `overflow: scroll` is because when focus on a input that will become fixed when I scroll down, it scrolls all the way up and perhaps this is a fix to it.

Comment: How are you calling the `smallTopCheck()` function?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have a smallTopCheck(); under the function. (If i remove the overflow:auto; it's working as it's supposed to)

Comment: So you only call it once when the page loads?

Comment: Yes an event is binded to the scroll event, so I just have to call it once.

Comment: If the window is >= 992 in width on load then the scroll event handler won't be bound. Also check the console for any errors

Comment: Yes I haven't posted to whole code, but simplied version. But I don't think that is necessary for the problem. I have some other code that removes the event when it's smaller then 992 and adds it again when above. (with .resize)

Comment: Ok, well the reason I'm asking about how it's setup is because what you've shown should work fine.

Comment: Ohh, that's strange because when I added the overflow:auto; to my code it stopped working. Maybe it's something else then.

Comment: Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6n3hhy1k/

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, it must be something else then.